# Django - Change a readonly_field in model_save

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class AlarmListAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
fieldsets = (
             (None, {'fields' : ('owner',) } ),
             ( 'Alarm List', {'fields': ('listName', 'alarms') } )
             )
readonly_fields = ('owner',)
def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
    """Save the model, and fill in the current user as owner"""
    if not change:
        print str(request.user.username)
        account = Account.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
        instance.owner = account #owner needs to be an account object
    instance.save()
```

But django doesn't add the owner field to the QueryDict, I guess because it doesn't add any readonly fields to QueryDict?

So I can't do something like this example:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, you can do this. My error was apparently coming from something else...